# Change the anonymous type to list of object in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am using Linq, and have a function shown below to fetch the data from a database, because when I pull this data into grid view, then I cannot object of TblSpareParts table to edit the data in grid

```
private void LoadParts()
{
        RST_DBDataContext conn = new RST_DBDataContext();
        var AllParts = (from s in conn.TblSpareParts
                        join m in conn.TblBikeModels on s.ModelID equals m.ModelID
                        select new { s.SPartName, s.SPartCode, s.SPartLocation, s.SPartID, s.TblBikeModel.ModelName }).ToArray();
        SParts_grid.ItemsSource = AllParts;
}
```

I want this function like this,

```
private void LoadParts()
{
            RST_DBDataContext conn = new RST_DBDataContext();
            List<TblSparePart> AllParts = (from s in conn.TblSpareParts
                            join m in conn.TblBikeModels on s.ModelID equals m.ModelID
                            select new { s.SPartName, s.SPartCode, s.SPartLocation, s.SPartID, s.TblBikeModel.ModelName }).ToList();
            SParts_grid.ItemsSource = AllParts;
}
```

So basically I want to change this part `var AllParts` to `List<TblSparePart> AllParts` and this `.ToArray();` to `.ToList();`

Comment: Then what is your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try change your code:

```
...
select new { s.SPartName, s.SPartCode, s.SPartLocation, s.SPartID, s.TblBikeModel.ModelName }).ToList();
...
```

to become

```
...
select new TblSparePart { 
    // partName, partCode, etc are TblSparePart class property
    partName = s.SPartName, 
    partCode = s.SPartCode,
    ...
    ...
}).ToList();
...
```

Comment: this gives error "Cannot initialize type TblSparePArt with a collection initializer because it does not implement System.Collections.IEnumerable

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

You cannot convert an anonymous object randomly to something else.. so even this won't work:

```
.ToList<TblSparePart>();
```

What you can do.. is actually not return anonymous objects.. return actual objects:

```
select new TblSparePart() {
    PartName = s.SPartName,
    PartCode = s.SPartCode
}
```

..etc.

Comment: what can i do ? this is also not working. because i have data from 2 tables i am using join. and i can not edit in grid

Comment: this gives error "Cannot initialize type TblSparePArt with a collection initializer because it does not implement System.Collections.IEnumerable